# Read in a paragraph witht getchar() and print it with a loop and putchar()

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, char

I have been working on this for a while and I am just wondering if it is possible to read in a paragraph with getchar() and then print it with putchar(). I know there are better methods to read in and print out a paragraph, but I am just messing around with C and am curious, here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
 {
     int c;
     printf( "Enter a value:");
     {
         for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
         {
             c = getchar( );
             putchar( c );
         }
         printf("\nthank you");
         printf("\n");
     }
     return 0;
}
```

My desired output would be:

Enter in a value/paragraph:

Your entered value is:

Comment: You don't need braces around for loop. If you are reading from a file, you can use one loop to both read character and print it. If you are reading from stdin (terminal), you'll be typing a character and printing it again (looks ugly).

Comment: `You don't need braces around for loop.` @saadtaame No, but it's easier to maintain and for others (i.e. people on StackOverflow) to read.

Comment: @Qix easier to read? that's a joke right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanted to capture the whole paragraph altogether.  You just need to stop when you press enter.

Here is the detail: `getchar()` will wait for enter anyway, and during that time, what ever you typed, will be stored in a ***buffer*** and shown on screen at the same time.  Then after you press enter, `getchar()` stops the wait, and return one char at a time so you can print them by `putchar`.

```
/* getchar example : typewriter */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int c;
  puts ("Enter text. Press enter to exit:");
  do {
    c=getchar();
    putchar (c);
  } while (c != '\n');
  return 0;
}
```